# ImageButton in WPF

Tags: wpf

Hy!!

I added a png to the debug dic. Now my Xaml Code:

```
<Button  Height="23"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,249,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57" ">
            <Image Source="\back.png"></Image>
        </Button>
```

The image won'T be found. I read some tutorials about a image in a button, but they all speak about resources etc.

Please write your answer step by step i am very new to WPF

Comment: Do you want the image to be embedded, a part of the exe/dll, or should the image be a separate file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the file to the solution. Open the image properties by right click on an image and make sure the build action for image is set to Resource.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the image to the solution and give the path Like and Set its property BuildAction to Resource

```
<Image  Margin="2" Source="/ApplicationName;component/FolderName/back.png" />
```